# how to display data from database into separate textbox in a new form, when user clicks an item that is in the listbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, ms-access, listbox

i am making a stock management system as part of my college project. i have a search bar and the result is outputted into a listbox. when the searched product is clicked the user will be taken to a new form where they will be able to view product information such as product name, price, quantity, stock. Also the user can delete and add stock. I have provided a screenshot of how it will look below.

[image: My image]

I'm new to Visual Studio, my problem is that i am unsure how to display the product information into the textbox, can someone please help.

This is my code so far in Form4, which is the homepage that contains the search result and listbox.

```
'Importing System.Data.OleDb, this is needed for connection with  database and is needed for database requirements.
Imports System.Data.OleDb

'This is the homepage
Public Class FrmHomePage
        'this code runs when the user searches for a certain product - " the search button event"
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        'The code below is used to open the database connection. 
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\MS Office\project.mdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE productID LIKE '" & txtSearch_Bar.Text & "'", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        'This if statement makes sure that the product the user is searching for is inside the database, if it isnt then a "no matches" message is displayed.
        If Not sdr.HasRows Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Matches")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'this clears the listbox so, if the user searches same product again, it wouldn't duplicate.
        lstbSearchResult.Items.Clear()
        'Checking for the item in database and outputting it to the listbox.
        While (sdr.Read())
            lstbSearchResult.Items.Add(sdr("ProductID"))
        End While

        'closing the database connection
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    'this private sub is basically a side menu which slides out when the user clicks the button "menu".
    'Inside the menu the user will have different options such As settings, About us, And more.
    Private Sub btnMenu_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMenu.Click
        PnlSide_Menu.Location = New Point(-183, 0)
        Do Until PnlSide_Menu.Location.X = -10
        PnlSide_Menu.Location = New Point(PnlSide_Menu.Location.X + 1, 0)
        Loop

        Do Until PnlSide_Menu.Location.X = 0
            PnlSide_Menu.Location = New Point(PnlSide_Menu.Location.X + 1, 0)
            Refresh()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
        Loop

    End Sub

    'private sub for closing the the side menu/side bar.
    Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnBack.Click
        PnlSide_Menu.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        Do Until PnlSide_Menu.Location.X = -170
            PnlSide_Menu.Location = New Point(PnlSide_Menu.Location.X - 1, 0)
            Refresh()
        Loop

        Do Until PnlSide_Menu.Location.X = -183
            PnlSide_Menu.Location = New Point(PnlSide_Menu.Location.X - 1, 0)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
        Loop

    End Sub

    'this is the logout button function. 
    'when clicked the user will be taken back to the login page.
    Private Sub btnLogOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogOut.Click
        Me.Close()
        FrmLogin.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstbSearchResult_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstbSearchResult.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
```

This code below is where i am planning to do the things mentioned above.

```
    'Click event of the result in listbox.
    Private Sub lstbSearchResult_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstbSearchResult.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\MS Office\project.mdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE productID LIKE '" & txtSearch_Bar.Text & "'", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        con.Close()

        frmProductForm.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You might want to research *data binding*.  You should also read [ask] and take the [tour].  `i am unsure how ...` is not a question and simply means you have not done enough research.  This is not a tutorial site

Comment: what up with u ? i don't get it. every time you are the first person to see my post and you cant even help, instead you criticise my post. Seriously, help if you can. I am not a professional or something to do everything right, i make some mistakes, im a beginner. so please stop discouraging. btw thanks for "data binding" @Plutonix

Comment: _first person to see my post and you can't even help_ and it follows with _btw thanks for "data binding"_.

Comment: Thats not how the site works.  Posts that are too broad, off topic and/or poorly researched are *supposed* to be discouraged (via downvotes).  Of course you can mitigate a great deal of this by doing more research and asking better questions.  Read [ask], take the [tour] and perhaps visit the [help] for details.  All but one of your posts has a negative score,  soon that will limit your ability to post  anything.

Comment: Ideally, a stock management (inventory) db would not save aggregate data. Enter transactions of incoming and outgoing stock and then calculate net balance from the raw data records. Are you required to use VB.net for your project?

Comment: Unfortunately at time i was selecting a project and a language i picked vb.net. Now it's too late for me to change language. What language do you think would of been better? @June7

Comment: Since you are using Access for data storage could have just used VBA, the programming language included with all MS Office apps. And use Access design objects (queries, forms, reports, controls).

Answer (score 0):

I put my explanations in with the code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        'The code below is used to open the database connection. 
        'Change Dim to Using - this takes care of disposing of objects you create with the End Using
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\MS Office\project.mdb")
            'You download every field in the table but you only use the productID field
            'the idea with database communication is to get in and out as quickly as possible
            'only ask for the data you need
            'Your user is actually typing in and searching for a productID?
            'A productID in a database is usually an Integer of a Long
            'Check what datatype this is. If this is a number, what does it mean to find a number LIKE another number?
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE productID LIKE '" & txtSearch_Bar.Text & "'", con)
                con.Open()
                Using sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    'This if statement makes sure that the product the user is searching for is inside the database, if it isnt then a "no matches" message is displayed.
                    If Not sdr.HasRows Then
                        MessageBox.Show("No Matches")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    'this clears the listbox so, if the user searches same product again, it wouldn't duplicate.
                    lstbSearchResult.Items.Clear()
                    'Checking for the item in database and outputting it to the listbox.
                    While (sdr.Read())
                        'Use a class to hold all your Product data
                        Dim p As New Product
                        p.ProductID = sdr.GetInt32(0) 'I am just guessing at the order of your fields
                        p.ProductName = sdr.GetString(1)
                        p.Price = sdr.GetDouble(2)
                        p.Section = sdr.GetInt32(3)
                        p.Supplier = sdr.GetString(4)
                        lstbSearchResult.Items.Add(p)
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
            'closing the database connection
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
    'Click event of the result in listbox.
    Private Sub lstbSearchResult_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstbSearchResult.Click
        'Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\jacob\Desktop\MS Office\project.mdb")
        'Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProduct WHERE productID LIKE '" & txtSearch_Bar.Text & "'", con)
        'con.Open()
        'Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        'con.Close()
        'You just got all this info in Button1.Click
        'and it is all saved in your list box
        frmProductForm.Show()
        Dim p As Product = DirectCast(lstbSearchResult.SelectedItem, Product)
        frmProductForm.txtProductName.Text = p.ProductName 'The names of the text boxes are guesses
        frmProductForm.txtProductID.Text = p.ProductID
        'etc.
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Product

    Public Sub New()
        'Default constructor
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(intProductID As Integer, strProductName As String, dblPrice As Double, intCurrentStock As Integer, intSection As Integer, strSupplier As String)
        ProductID = intProductID
        ProductName = strProductName
        Price = dblPrice
        CurrentStock = intCurrentStock
        Section = intSection
        Supplier = strSupplier
    End Sub

    Private _ProductID As Integer
    Public Property ProductID As Integer
        Get
            Return _ProductID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _ProductID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ProductName As String
    Public Property ProductName As String
        Get
            Return _ProductName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ProductName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Price As Double
    Public Property Price As Double
        Get
            Return _Price
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _Price = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _CurrentStock As Integer
    Public Property CurrentStock As Integer
        Get
            Return _CurrentStock
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _CurrentStock = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Section As Integer
    Public Property Section As Integer
        Get
            Return _Section
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _Section = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Supplier As String
    Public Property Supplier As String
        Get
            Return _Supplier
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Supplier = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String 'This is what the list box calls to get what to put in its text
        Return $"{_ProductID}  {_ProductName}"
    End Function

End Class
```